# Is it possible to limit upload speed for my local dev server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am trying to debug my upload progress bar but on my local dev server everything uploads instantly has you might expect... Using the prod server is not an option...

Is it possible to simulate a slow connection with axios to upload my photos and debug my code ?

Comment: Simulate slow network speeds in your browser’s developer tools, usually a dropdown in the network section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Chrome you can open the developer tools and use the network conditions tool. Hit the burger menu and navigate to More Tools -> Network Conditions.

[image]

Once there you can throttle the network speed:

[image]